# Intrusive list threadsafe - best way

Tags: c++, multithreading, linked-list

How do you create an intrusive slist (boost) that is threadsafe so that multiple threads can remove items or add items?

I'd want fairly fine grained locking; so I can lock only the necessary nodes and not the whole list each time.

Do I just write a wrapper class around boost slist or is it better to just implement it myself?

Comment: Fine grained locking comes at cost of more locks acquired and released. Are you sure your code would really benefit from locking/unlocking each individual node separately?

Comment: @blaze: The issue is that the list will need to be accessible to 4-5 threads and I don't want the whole thing locked up each time I need to add or remove a node....  Is the overhead of locking indivual nodes higher compared to the time a thread might end up waiting for (an)other thread(s)?

Comment: It depends on your application.  Locking individual nodes might be seen as a micro-optimization better left to after you've profiled your app's performance with global locking.  On the other hand, some applications like high-throughput in-memory database systems would benefit from row-level locking from the word go.

Comment: It depends on your mutex implementation and list usage pattern. If each thread quickly scan 50 items, removes one and then processes data for 1 second, 6 threads will almost never block each other with global lock. And if your mutexes are kernel-based and require system call to lock and release - it would be PAINFULLY slow to lock even 10 nodes on each call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the approach here that uses C++0x atomic operations (if you have access to C++0x). It adresses the multi-producer/consumer approach.

http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/210604448